# Postman response in csv format

Tags: java, postman

I'm trying to send my response in postman in csv format , but postman doesn't interpred ("\n") as next line,

here my code response:

```
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
body.append("lastname ; firstname");
body.append("\n");
```

postman response is in this format lastname ; firstname\n exlastname, exFirstname

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind to edit your question to a specific problem? It doesn't explain the same!

Answer (score 0):

Workaround to add a new line here would be using separate `console.log` statements to achieve the desired newline effect.

Something like `console.log("new", '\n', "line", '\n', "added");`